# Error using local iis with Visual Studio 2012 and 2013

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Team,

After hours of banging, no clues what so ever. For a simple Asp.Net web app on Visual Studio 2013(on 2012 also same problem) I press F5 and behold

> CS0016: Could not write to output file
>   'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\promo\db1af688\37895338\App_global.asax.jl_q7efp.dll' -- 'Access
>   is denied. '

This is a simple set up, windows 8 pro, not in any network and IIS installed.

The app pool is `DefaultAppPool` with `ApplicationPoolIdentity`.

Can somebody throw at least some pointers please?

Comment: Two things: one, perhaps obvious, have you restarted VS and/or the computer? And the second, what happens when you run VS as an administrator? I only ask since I see the "Access is Denied" there, so that could be a good test.